# Make User Option When Stage Failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

how do i make user input if there is an error in one of the stages in the jenkins pipeline? I need input options like "rerun" to rerun the failed stage, "skip" to give success to the failed stage then continue to the next stage or "abort" to abort all stages in the pipeline, can someone help me?

i need example of code of my problem